# Get Current Location Path in JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I've a jsp with below lines:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a id="iso3_dan" href="/?lang=iso3:dan&locale=iso3:dan">Dansk</a></li>
    <li><a id="iso3_deu" href="/?lang=iso3:deu&locale=iso3:DEU">Deutsch</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Its basically used to show the language drop-down. Now, I need to make the URL in such a way that it'll append the current page action as well.

I'm using Struts 2

In browser, if I hit admin menu, the url changes to

```
http://<portalIp>/admin
```

if I hit marketing menu, it changes to

```
http://<portalIp>/marketing
```

Now, what I need to do is that I need to append this /admin & /marketing actions in the language. So, if you're on Marketing page, I need to pass the marketing action as shown below:

```
<a id="iso3_dan" href="/marketing?lang=iso3:dan&locale=iso3:dan">Dansk</a>
<a id="iso3_deu" href="/marketing?lang=iso3:deu&locale=iso3:DEU">Deutsch</a>
```

If you're on admin page, I need to pass that current action as shown below:

```
<a id="iso3_dan" href="/admin?lang=iso3:dan&locale=iso3:dan">Dansk</a>
<a id="iso3_deu" href="/admin?lang=iso3:deu&locale=iso3:DEU">Deutsch</a>
```

How do I pass current action in JSP? I tried below:

```
<a id="iso3_deu" href="<%= request.getRequestURL() %>/?lang=iso3:deu&locale=iso3:DEU">Deutsch</a>
```

But this did not work. How do I get the path of just the action without adding any Javascript code?

Note: I cannot use Javascript because of search engine optimizations. Otherwise, javscript function document.location.pathname solves this issue.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `admin` or `marketing` are name of your action which has been mapped to there respected action classes.
If this is the case Struts2 provides a way to access the action name using `ActionContext`.

you can create a utility method in your action class/Base action class something like

```
public String getActionName() {
        ActionContext a = ActionContext.getContext();
        Object value = a.getName();
        return value;
}
```

`ActionContext` provide a reference to the context and you will be able to get action name as well many other valuable information there in the stack.

Answer (score -1):

You can get action path in your controller and pass to jsp, so forward to jsp url like :

```
your.jsp?action=/admin
```

and output parameter in jsp.

Comment: Okay,if you want to get action path, you can get action path in controller and passed to jsp.